# \csvreader doesn't show the table

Tags: csvsimple

Mainly I want to do something similar this-

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
This is the summary 
\csvreader[autotabular]{coefficient.csv}
\end{document}
```

but this is not compiled

My `coefficient.csv` looks like-

```
"","Estimate","Pr(>|t|)"
"(Intercept)",3083.10823266321,0.410258948870845
"academicYear",-154.682625625893,0.586945960271761
"tuitionOfferPerMonth",166.418331237849,0.626598991149528
"tutionsYouHaveDone",88.1170833442809,0.687790764988264
"result",2174.73550930876,0.0319792901914711
"teachingHour",762.859932701096,0.421832171976142
"subjectsYouTaught",-99.4216388435531,0.831181012593366
"daysInWeek",-471.260444393369,0.409951748818405
"tuitionType",469.36175552496,0.446727615621479
"studentClass",159.808778458308,0.249053825131443
"Dept.science",1902.80982919603,0.105027526587972
"Hall",-1057.61231171402,0.196789600388924
```

I want to learn the `csvsimple` from basic.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: You should definitely start providing complete documents and not snippets, like you often do. And given that you get errors from that code, you shouldn't be surprised that the output is wrong. And you should have a look at the [`csvsimple` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf), in particular section 2 on page 8, which describes how `\csvreader` is supposed to be used.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. My original document is so big. So, I don't want to attach this. I edited my question although the sample code not run.

Comment: You're not supposed to show your entire document, you're supposed to show exactly what you now have: the smallest complete document necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. see line 86 on  [this](https://www.overleaf.com/11905120nypgwzmckdxh)

Comment: Why? What does that show that the code above doesn't? Your question is about why `\csvreader` doesn't work, isn't the rest of the document irrelevant in that case? And if you look at the manual (link above) you might see that you're using `\csvreader` wrong. (Manuals can be useful, learn to read them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in section 2 of the `csvsimple` manual, the `\csvreader` macro takes *three* mandatory arguments, while you've just added one. That is, the general format is

```
\csvreader[<options>]{<file name>}{<assignments>}{<command list>}
```

while you've just used

```
\csvreader[<options>]{<file name>}
```

(The `\csvautotabular` macro on the other hand, as seen in [Abo Ammar's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401277/) has just one mandatory argument, the file name.)

The arguments:

1. The first mandatory argument is the filename of the `.csv` file.
2. The second argument assigns macros to the content of the various columns. For example, if you had a `.csv` file that looked like

   ```
   a,b
   1,2
   3,4
   ```

   then you would use

   ```
   a=\foo,b=\bar
   ```

   in the second mandatory argument, to define the two macros `\foo` and `\bar`, referring to the `a` and `b` columns respectively.
3. The third argument is where you define the format of your table rows, using the macros defined in the second argument. For example

   ```
   \bar & \foo
   ```

   to print the `b` column first, and `a` column second.

- `\csvreader` also has an optional argument, where you define the column types of your table (e.g. `tabular=cc` for two centred columns), and any other formatting you need.

A complete example below, using some bits from the example in section 3.4 of the manual. To remove the quotation marks (`"`) from the first column output, I load the `xstring` package and use `\StrDel{\name}{"}` instead of `\name` in the row format. That will delete all occurrences of `"`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xstring} % defines \StrDel
\usepackage{booktabs} % defines \toprule,\midrule,\bottomrule
\begin{document}
\csvreader[
  % set up the columns in the table
  tabular=ccc,
  % define the content of the first row
  table head=\toprule Name & Estimate & $\mathrm{Pr}(>\mid t)$ \\ \midrule,
  % add rule after table
  table foot=\bottomrule
 ]{coefficient.csv}% filename
{""=\name,"Estimate"=\estimate,"Pr(>|t|)"=\Pr}% define macros that refer to the columns you want to use
{\StrDel{\name}{"} & \estimate & \Pr} % format of rows

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't it work if I don't define macro for column?

Comment: Why did you write the file content again in the code although you use `filePath`?

Comment: The `""` should be omit. I want to omit these without changing `.csv` because it's csv formate.

Comment: @alhelal 1) No, you must assign macro names to columns, but you don't have to assign *all* the columns. 2) The `filecontents` stuff is only to make the example self-contained, you can delete it as you already have the file. 3) Load the `xstring` package and use `\StrDel{\name}{"}` instead of `\name` in the row format.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}

This is the summary 

\csvautotabular[respect dollar=false]{coefficient.csv}

\end{document}
```

With the `coefficient.csv` file contents

```
,Estimate, Pr$(>|t|)$
(Intercept),3083.10823266321,0.410258948870845
academicYear,-154.682625625893,0.586945960271761
tuitionOfferPerMonth,166.418331237849,0.626598991149528
tutionsYouHaveDone,88.1170833442809,0.687790764988264
result,2174.73550930876,0.0319792901914711
teachingHour,762.859932701096,0.421832171976142
subjectsYouTaught,-99.4216388435531,0.831181012593366
daysInWeek,-471.260444393369,0.409951748818405
tuitionType,469.36175552496,0.446727615621479
studentClass,159.808778458308,0.249053825131443
Dept.science,1902.80982919603,0.105027526587972
Hall,-1057.61231171402,0.196789600388924
```

> [image]

Comment: Isn't it possible without changing the content of `coefficient.csv`? I know `csvautotabular`. You give me the solution with `csvreader`.